# What is Dr. Elliott doing in this scene?

Tags: dressed-to-kill

In *Dressed to Kill*, when Dr. Elliott was shot by the female police officer, as **SHE** tried to kill Liz, we hear from Murino and Dr. Levy that Dr. Elliott is sent to an insane asylum. Then after some time [this](https://youtu.be/mEq3kkRZUwM) appears, we can see that a nurse is taking care of mentally disabled people who were sleeping and when she tries to cover Dr. Elliott with a blanket **HE** grabs her by the throat and makes her to lose consciousness, after this he strips her and the scene goes away.

I'm having trouble in understanding this scene because **Bobbi** used to attack those women who aroused the male side of **HER**. But in this scene, why is Dr. Elliott, that is **HE**, killing her (or rather stripping her)?

Comment: Isn't this part of Liz's nightmare? ["surreal scene depicting Dr. Elliott’s escape from the insane asylum where he strangles the nurse (...) now we have a POV approaching Liz’s house where she is showering inside. Bobbi a la nurse has entered the house and is waiting. Liz senses danger, and spies the nurses’ shoes just outside the bathroom. Oh no! She tries to sneak quietly out of the shower but Bobbi is actually right beside the shower and (s)he slices his razor deeply through Liz’s throat. (...) **Liz jumps awake screaming in bed**"](http://www.cultprojections.com/deeptrash/dressed-to-kill)

Comment: @BCdotWEB I think it may right because Bobbi took the shoe off the nurse and put it on her body and then this same shoe is being focused in the shower scene of Liz.